# How to remove prefix from url in PHP/Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, variables

I have a url inside of a `<p>` tag assigned to a data array. I entered in the following code:

```
     $link = home_url();




   'side_by_side_content' => [ 
        "img" => [
            "src" => "/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/hello.jpg",
            "alt" => "Hello"
        ],
        "title" => "Hello World",
        "text" => "<p>Sorry! It appears the page you're looking for cannot be found. You can continue on to <a href=\'<?php echo $link; ?>\'>test.com Homepage</a></p>"
    ]
```

So when I run this code, the url comes up as test.com`/<?php echo $link; ?>` .It needs to come up on the homepage or just test.com is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: What do you mean "when you run this code".  How do you run this code? This looks like it's specifically a format for a plugin or theme.  Also, use your brower's developer tools - or better yet, do a "View Source" in your browser, and share the _rendered_ HTML with us.  In WordPress, there are many filters that could be applied to text, but it's impossible to know because you haven't shared with us how this is being rendered.

Answer (score 2):

You're declaring php inside a php.

simply do this:

```
'<p>Sorry! It appears the page you\'re looking for cannot be found. You can continue on to <a href="'.$link.'">test.com Homepage</a></p>'
```

Comment: When I put that in the way you have it, I get: http://test.com/href='http://test.com'

Comment: Simply echo-ing the above code, I just tested it again and it works fine. Are you maybe using any content filters to output the html? ..which maybe can mess it!

Just in case, try the edited version (swapped quotes with double-quotes)

Comment: @MikeL5799 - Your question is unclear.  You need to explain how your code is being processed / rendered, you need to use your Brower's Developer tools to inspect the rendered markup, and share what's actually happening.

Comment: I just changed it and now I get this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''.$link.'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ']' in /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/akc/404.php on line 48

Comment: @cale_b I explained how the code was being processed in right here in the question: So when I run this code, the url comes up as test.com/<?php echo $link; ?>

Comment: It is not up to @FisnikTahiri to keep walking with you through you trying to make this work.  See my comment above in this answer, and to your question.  Until you ask a complete and clear question, it's unfair to ask someone to help you try and figure out what you are doing.

Comment: I'll have to agree with @cale_b on this. But since we're already here, try to simply put a simple href without the $link variable; like so: `'text' => '<p>my link <a href="http://test.com">is this</a>.</p>'` and see if it prints correctly.

Comment: @FisnikTahiri I solved this yesterday. Thanks for your help. At least you were positive about it.

Answer (score 0):

1. you are using php inside php
2. a tag was not properly set, just use sth like

   href="'.$link.'">test.com

Comment: but with single quotes around ".$link."

Comment: Code-only answers aren't useful.  What did you change? Why? Why didn't it work for OP?

Comment: When I do it like that it doesn't work it just gives me: test.com/href='http://test.com'

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved the issue by doing this:

`href=".'/'."` and also `href='$link'`

Thanks for all your help guys.